# How to insert an "Select All" option in dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown list with a filter for `IN` and `OUT` values. Here everything works.

```
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
    <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
    <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
</select>
```

TS

```
  public selectedBrand: any;
  public onChangeType(type: any) {
    this.selectedBrand = type;
    console.log(this.selectedBrand);

    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts.filter(
        (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
    console.log(this.filteredCustomer);
  }
```

I would now like to add a `SELECT ALL` to retrieve the elements of `IN` or `OUT`.

What am I missing in my code, please?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just change `item.type === this.selectedBrand` to `item.type === this.selectedBrand || this.selectedBrand === "ALL"` and add an option to the dropdownlist with "ALL" as value.

Comment: @devostOliv I've answered your question, but you've again left out a lot of relevant code - in fact the exact same code as your last question. I only know how to answer this because I answered your last question. Please include ALL relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have a function to remove the filter like so:

```js
resetFilter() {
    this.selectedBrand = '';
    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts
}
```

You could call this with a button click or whatever you like.

---

Or you can put another option in your dropdown, and check for it in the `onChangeType` method.

```html
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
    <option [value]="'ALL'">ALL</option>
    <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
    <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
</select>
```

```
public onChangeType(type: any) {
    if (type === 'ALL') {
      this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts;
      return;
    }

    this.selectedBrand = type;
    console.log(this.selectedBrand);

    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts.filter(
        (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
    console.log(this.filteredCustomer);
  }
```

---

Also you should change your `ngModel` to two way binding `[(ngModel)]`

```html
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
```

Then it will automatically be synced with the `selectedBrand` property - both ways.

So you can remove `this.selectedBrand = type` from `onChangeType()`.

```js
public onChangeType(type: any) {
    if (type === 'ALL') {
      this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts;
      return;
    }

    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts.filter(
        (item) => item.type === type
    );
  }
```